# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Drivercom.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im trying to establish a connection but having the mentioned error.

```
     try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cams?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "root");

                System.out.println("Connected to Database successfully");
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                s.assignStall(s.numOfStall + 1, stallOwnerId, category, iCanSelected, 
                        contact, name, add, email, unitNo, stallName);
                s.showAssignedStall();
    /*
                int result = st.executeUpdate(
                        "INSERT INTO StallOwner" (sId, sCat, cant, sContact,
                        sName, sAdd, sEmail, sUnitNo, sStallName) VALUES(
                                "")
                        )
              */  
                jTextFieldUserId.setText("");
                jTextFieldName.setText("");
                jTextFieldAddress.setText("");
                jTextFieldContact.setText("");
                jTextFieldEmail.setText("");
                jTextFieldUnitNo.setText("");
                jTextFieldStallName.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

This is my 1st time with JDBC. Please help

Comment: You are missing the MySQL connector JAR file from build path.

Comment: I don't think it is the buildpath - this is a runtime exception not a compile error

Comment: When you face `ClassNotFoundException:` ,Then first please check related jar is there or not on your class path.

Comment: why are you making new instance of driver ,
"Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()" , this driver class only needs to be loaded , which is already done by class.forname() , why do u need new instance then ??

Answer (score 1):

Your will need to add the jar file containing the mysql driver to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to include the `mysql.jar`
if you are using **ECLIPSE IDE** then follow these steps

1. right click on your project
2. go to buildpath
3. click configure build path
4. click add external jars
5. give the path to mysql.jar

Comment: This will not work unless he is using the same IDE as you.  Maybe he is using vi on a linux box.

Comment: @user2310289 I forgot to mention eclipse,I will correct it now

Comment: Although if he were using vi on a Linux box he probably wouldn't be asking this question ;)

Comment: @bgp I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing mysql jdbc jar(jar containing the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`) on your classpath. Add the required jar on your classpath.